# curl autologin does not write cookies

Tags: php, curl, authentication, https, external

I try to login with cUrl posting json-data, server responds that login is successful, but it does not write session into cookies, my code:

```
<?php
$json_url = 'https://www.site.com/Login';
$json_string = '{"username":"user","password":"12345"}';

$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json;  charset=utf-8') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
echo $result;
?>
```

I see the cookies that need to be written in header, but they are not writing to my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookies created with a server-side curl request cannot be sent to a browser. You cannot set cookies for a domain other than the one the script is running from. e.g. you cannot have your PHP code log into facebook, and transfer the facebook session token back to the user and have it be usable on the actual facebook site. If you try, you'll find that the browser does set a cookie with the name/value you set, but it'll be restricted to **YOUR** site, not facebook.com

Comment: @mark-b yes, I expected so, but is there any workaround? How can I send json-data on client-side? I need something like this, but with json-data POST.
<form action="https://external.com/login" method="POST">
<input name="username" value="user" />
<input name="password" value="12345" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: you can't, not if you want cookies to work. either the user submits directly to the site you're trying to log them into, so cookies work, or you proxy **EVERYTHING** they do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cookie file in order to save and read them:

```
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"ciasteczka.txt"); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"ciasteczka.txt");
```

(ciasteczka is cookies in Polish)

Comment: right, in other words in that array you need to add two new keys (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE) both having the value the path to a file with write permissions on